# Regular expression for variable assignment

Tags: regex

I'm currently working on a mini project. This mini project is like a compiler - so far, it's able to determine a valid variable declaration like this below through a finite state automaton I wrote:

```
var a_123 = abc + 10 % 9 - 1.25 * 100; //this is just an example operation

where var = type
      a_123 = identifier
      abc = another identifier
```

My question is, can I validate the right hand side of the equation using a regex? I'm fairly new to Regular Expressions - and I'm only able to solve the left hand side of it. 
This is the regex I made for the LHS:

```
^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,39}$
```

And this is my attempt to make the RHS:

```
"^([-+/*%]\d+(\.\d+)?)*
```

It will fail with the identifier part though. How can I expand the regex for RHS so that it will accept variable names?

Comment: Recognizing an entire expression via regex wouldn't do you any good - you need to individually recognize the components of the expression in order to make any sense of them.  Validating that the components fit together in a meaningful way (balanced parentheses, no two binary operators in a row, etc.) happens at a higher conceptual level than parsing the tokens.

Comment: Yes, I agree that recognizing it as a whole is just bad. :) And good thing you mentioned about parentheses! I missed that on my automaton code. Thanks. So as you said, I need to check each components... alright, I'll try once again. Thanks for the hindsight.

Comment: I think you can use a regex like this `^((^\s*|[-+*\/%]\s+)((\d+?\.\d+|\d+)|[a-zA-Z_]\w+)(\s+|$))+$` ;).

Comment: okay so this is what's working so far: 
'^(^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,39})=((\d|([-+/*%]\d+(\.\d+)?)*)*)$'
This regex can evaluate expressions like this one below:
_a123 = 10 % 2 + 1 / 4 - 3 * 8.5
so my remaining problem is when there is variable name in the RHS like 
_a123 = 10 % 2 + 1 / 4 - 3 * 8.5 + abc
I know this is quite a pointless task and writing an FSM would be better when it comes to parsing complex patterns such as this but I believe it's doable. :)